# In Domino Designer is there a way to open a MessageBox

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

In Domino Designer is there a way to open a MessageBox with a button to then enable the user to input something, then paste the users input into another field?

Answer (score 3):

Since you want the user to be able to input content you should use the [Lotusscript InputBox method](http://'http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/LSAZ_INPUTBOX_FUNCTION.html).

Comment: There's also the very handy NotesUIWorkspace.Dialogbox method, which will allow you to have greater control over the type of user input (assuming correct design of the dialog form); you can also do the equivalent as HTML and JavaScript in the browser (with or without a pseudo-modal overlay). The dialogbox has some distinct advantages, especially where dates are concerned.

Answer (score 3):

Formula language allows you to write a one-liner for this:

```
FIELD YourField := @Prompt([OkCancelEdit]; "Enter Your Value"; "Type your value in the box below:"; "Default Value"); ""
```

Put this code into a formula button.